# Understanding constraint violations in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL and I'm a bit struggling -

Consider the next snippet of code:

```
CREATE TABLE Trip
(
    tnum INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,   
    location TEXT NOT NULL, 
    duration INTEGER DEFAULT(5),
    difficulty INTEGER CHECK(difficulty > 0 AND difficulty < 7),
    CHECK (difficulty <= 6 AND difficulty >= 3)
);

CREATE TABLE Company
(
    cid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    diffiname TEXT NOT NULL, 
    estYear Integer NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Offer
(
    cid INTEGER,
    tnum INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES Company(cid),
    FOREIGN KEY(tnum) REFERENCES Trip(tnum)
);
```

I'm experiencing two constrains violations, the first one is that i'm able to add `Trips` with `difficulty` 0, or trips with `difficulty` 7 with `duration` 2 (Desired constraint - Trips of duration more than 6 have difficulty of at least 3) -

[image]

And the second violation, is that i'm able to add `Offer`s that consist of `tnum` and `cid` that don't even exist.

Comment: "(difficulty <= 6 OR duration >= 3)" -- can you think of a number that fails this test?

Comment: @DavidAldridge is right you probably want `(duration <= 6 AND difficulty >= 3)`

Comment: You guys are right, but still, after fixing as you suggested, constraints are still violated

Comment: well as you can see, there are several constraint and several errors. try to simplify things and add one constraint each time and test it. dont start testing all three at once.

Comment: You should probably add a NOT NULL clause to the columns used in REFERENCES in table offer. Otherwise, "violating" rows can be introduced if they have NULLs in those columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we rephrase your constraint as the logically equivalent,

```
difficulty INTEGER not NULL
    CHECK(difficulty between 1 and 6), 
    CHECK(difficulty between 3 and 6)
```

it becomes clear that the second constraint controls, because anything between 3 & 6 is also between 1 & 6.

> i'm able to add Trips with difficulty 0

That wouldn't be possible with the above.  Using `and` and `or`, though, it's easy to get tangled up and describe a constraint other than what you intend.

Regarding the foreign key constraints, the SQL as it now stands looks correct, but @Gordon Linoff's answer indicates that the original version of your post included errors that would not have correctly constrained `Offer`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your foreign key reference to `trip` is wrong on `offer`:

```
CREATE TABLE Offer
(
    cid INTEGER,
    tnum INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY(cid) REFERENCES Company(cid),
    FOREIGN KEY(tnum) REFERENCES Trip(cid)
--------------------------------------^ tnum
);
```

As for the check constraints, I don't understand the intent of this:

```
CHECK (difficulty <= 6 OR duration >= 3)
```

Do you intend `AND`?  Do you intend `AND difficulty >= 3` instead of `duration`?